# keda-operator-metrics-apiserver: no matching metrics found for s0-prometheus-http_requests_in_progress

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, keda, horizontalpodautoscaler

I am getting below error on **keda-operator-metrics-apiserver** pod logs when trying to scale using KEDA.

`E0602 05:26:23.321583       1 status.go:71] apiserver received an error that is not an metav1.Status: &status.Error{s:(*status.Status)(0xc00105e2c0)}: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = error when getting metric values no matching metrics found for s0-prometheus-http_requests_in_progress`

As we can see in this error, it says, `no matching metrics found for s0-prometheus-http_requests_in_progress`. It has automatically added `s0-prometheus-` to the metricName. What is the reason for that?

How can I solve this issue and read the metrics and scale my container?

I have created a KEDA ScaledObject as below.

```
apiVersion: keda.sh/v1alpha1
kind: ScaledObject
metadata:
  name: keda-so-prmts
  namespace: mynamespace
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    name: abc-test-yy
  pollingInterval:  10
  cooldownPeriod:   300
  minReplicaCount:  1
  maxReplicaCount:  10
  triggers:
  - type: prometheus
    metadata:
      serverAddress: http://10.1.254.12:9090
      metricName: http_requests_in_progress
      query: sum(http_requests_in_progress{action="getData", container="abc-test-yy", controller="Fetching", endpoint="8080", exported_endpoint="api/FetchService/getData/{productId}", job="abc-test-yy", method="POST", namespace="mynamespace", service="abc-test-yy"})by(container)
      threshold: '1'
      namespace: mynamespace
```